# Global connection via netcat

Tags: linux, bash, ip, ip-address, netcat

I would like to make very easy connection between two devices:
*Device One* is in **WiFi1** and *Device Two* in **WiFi2**;
The *Device One* has local address **192.168.4.65**;
The **WiFi1** has IP address **12.34.56.78**
(only example)

I want to run `"nc -l <some parameters>"` on my first device, and `"nc <address>"` on the second, so they connect;

I know, what to do if I want to connect two devices in a local area network;

But for global I have no Idea, what `<some parameters>` and `<address>` should be; can someone please help?

Comment: Google "How do I set up port forwarding?" for how to get your router to forward connections targeting 12.34.56.78:1234 to 192.168.4.65:1234. Then `nc -l 1234` will be reachable with `nc 12.34.56.78 1234`

Comment: this isn't a programming problem, it's router configuration. [su] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Yeah, Guys, thx; I found it in my router settings; so appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @that-other-guy and @Barmar!!

You can do it by managing your router settings; If you configurate port forwarding, it will move you to the device you want to;

> targeting 12.34.56.78:1234 to 192.168.4.65:1234. Then `nc -l 1234` will be reachable with `nc 12.34.56.78 1234`